# For each group, count the number of dates that occur before each date in other list

Tags: r, date, group-by

| Date1 | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-17 | 1 |
| 2023-06-23 | 2 |

```
Date2 <- c("2023-05-31", "2023-06-30", "2023-07-31")
```

So for each Group, I would like to count the total number of Date1 that occur before each Date2.

Answer (score 0):

One way of counting `conditions` is to evaluate the elements of your target vector.
To make this work for "dates", make sure you have coerced the vector to the correct type, i.e. `date`.
For correct types the logical evaluation will work.

In your case you have a date, e.g. 2023-05-17.
You can check each element of another vector how they relate to each other.

```
check_date <- as.Date("2023-05-17")
Date2      <- as.Date(c("2023-05-31", "2023-06-30", "2023-07-31"))

# let's check the condition on the vector,
# are my Date2 "older" than the check_date
Date2 > check_date
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE

# count the conditions
sum(Date2 > check_date)
[1] 3
```

You can operate this on your data.frame. For this you can iterate over your Date1 column:

((Note: you can emulate this with the tidyverse, I use base-R here))

```
df <- data.frame(
   Date1 = c("2023-05-17", "2023-06-23")
 , Group = c(1,2)
)

df$DatesBefore = lapply(df$Date1, function(x){sum(x > Date2)})
```

This yields

```
df
      Date1 Group DatesBefore
1 2023-05-17     1           0
2 2023-06-23     2           1
```